# How simulate clicks/ui events and loop them on Android?

Tags: android, ui-automation, ui-testing, android-uiautomator

How can I how simulate clicks/ui events button clicks and loop them on Android ?

I need an app to do this on Android, so it clicks on specific coordinates on the screen at specific times and loop these sequences

Comment: If you are referring to clicking on your own app's UI, there may be better solutions to whatever problem you are trying to solve that way. If you are referring to clicking on the UI of other apps, that is not generally possible, for security reasons.

Comment: You can use `UI Automator` for clicking on UI by getting ids and performing click on them.